# How can I draw using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am very beginner in tikz !
I want to draw picture with tikz:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried something so far?

Comment: Not about this picture but I draw many simple pics.

Comment: It is very easy using 'tkz-euclide' package. Follow the example from http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/tkz-euclide/tkz-euclide-screen.pdf at page 39.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can take advantage of `calc` and `intersections` library to draw this picture.

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth]

\coordinate (O) at (0,0);

\draw (-120:2)coordinate (B) arc (-120:120:2)coordinate(C);

\draw[<->] (-120:2.3) arc (-120:120:2.3)node[midway,fill=white]{$\beta$};

\path[name path=line1](C)--($(C)!2!-90:(O)$);
\path[name path=line2](O)--+(-5,0);

\fill [name intersections={of=line1 and line2}]
(intersection-1) circle (1.5pt);

\foreach \i in {O,B,C}
{\fill (\i)circle(1.5pt);}

\draw (B)--(intersection-1)--(C);
\draw [dashed](C)--(O)--(intersection-1);

\draw($(C)!0.1!(O)$)coordinate(c1)--($(c1)!1!90:(C)$)coordinate(c2)--($(c2)!1!90:(c1)$);

\draw[<->] (intersection-1)+(1,0)arc(0:30:1)node[midway,right,font=\scriptsize]{$\alpha$};

\draw[<->] ($(intersection-1)!0.3cm!90:(C)$)--($(C)!0.3cm!-90:(intersection-1)$)node[midway,sloped,fill=white]{$d/r$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 7):

I started using tikz a while ago and i found great joy in doing the tutorials of the outstanding official documentation:

[Official tikz & pgf documentation](http://mirror.switch.ch/ftp/mirror/tex/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf)

The tutorials (starting at page 29) cover about everything that you need to do.

If you prefer less text there's also a great introduction to tikz, called "A very minimal introduction to Tikz:

[Minimal Introduction to Tikz](http://cremeronline.com/LaTeX/minimaltikz.pdf)